Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: weather.io
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: 52.33.207.7: Invalid response from https://introvert.com/?domain=weather.io: "\n\n\n\t<meta charset="utf-8">\n\t<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">\n\t<meta name="viewpo"
Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.
Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile C:\Certbot\log\letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
